# Using dataType: "json" does not run AJAX code

Tags: php, ajax, json, types, undefined

I have been searching for hours and haven't found any solutions for my problem.
This is my jQuery/Ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $(".submit_btn").click(function () { 
      var name = $("input#name").val();  
      var dataString = 'query='+$("#query").val()+'&facebook='+facebook+'&twitter='+twitter;
      $.ajax({  
          type: "POST", 
          url: "selectDataSets.php",
          dataType: "json",
          data: dataString,  
          success: function(data) { 

            alert ("hello");

          }  
        });  
        return false;  
  });  
});
```

Now my selectDataSets.php code:

```
<?
include_once 'config.php';
if ((isset($_POST['facebook'])||isset($_POST['twitter']))&&isset($_POST['query'])) { 

$elements=0;
$dataSet=array();
$tt=array();
$fb=array();

mysql_connect($config['database_url'], $config['database_user'], $config['database_password']) or die(mysql_error());
$queries = explode(";", $_POST['query']);

foreach ($queries as $query){
    if(isset($_POST['facebook']) && $_POST['facebook'] == true){

        mysql_select_db("facebook") or die(mysql_error());
        $mysql_query = "SELECT * FROM page WHERE lower(name) LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($query))."%'";

        // Perform Query
        $result = mysql_query($mysql_query);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $set = array(
                    "name" => str_replace("-","",$row['name']),
                    "likes" => $row['likes'],
                    "about"   => $row['talkAbout'],
                    "source"   => "Facebook (Page)",
                    "id"   => $row["id"],
                    "query"   => $query
            );
            $fb[$elements]=$set;
            $elements++;
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);

    }
 }

mysql_close();
echo json_encode($fb);
}
```

With `dataType: "json"`, the `alert("Hello")` does not work, as well as nothing that I add inside the success callback. Although when I remove `dataType: "json"`, the alert works, but the variable data is not recognized as JSON (as I keep getting undefined when I try to do `data[0].name`), even though I have checked and data is on the format `[ { "name: ... } ]`, which I guess is correct JSON. I don't know what else to do, as I have a similar (almost the same) code on another php file that works perfectly with the `dataType: "json"`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are probably getting malformed JSON. Which browser are you using? I recommend Google Chrome. Try placing a console.log() statement in a complete() or error() callback in addition to your success() callback. This will give you additional insight. It's likely that the parser is crashing on bad JSON. Then, [open the devtools console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

Comment: Like this?
, error: function(data) {
 console.log();
}
, complete: function(data) {
 console.log();
}

I tried this and nothing appeared on the console..

Comment: No, like this: `error: function (xhr, status, error) { console.log(status, error); }, complete: function (xhr, status) { console.log(status); }`

Comment: That worked, thanks for clarifying!
I got this on the console: parsererror SyntaxError {} and 
parsererror

Comment: See, there's some type of error with your JSON. Make sure you have no null values. Can I see an example of your JSON output?

Comment: Here is an example of my JSON output:

{"fb":[{"name":"Barack Obama","likes":"36460530","about":"1062233","source":"Facebook (Page)","id":"93","query":"obama"},{"name":"Michelle Obama","likes":"9661729","about":"16790","source":"Facebook (Page)","id":"104","query":"obama"},{"name":"Brock Obama","likes":"176969","about":"26774","source":"Facebook (Page)","id":"105","query":"obama"},{"name":"Impeach Obama","likes":"79659","about":"9946","source":"Facebook (Page)","id":"106","query":"obama"}, ...

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't post it all here, it wouldnt fit. But there rest is just more of the above. The end is like this: {"name":"Proud of Obama","likes":"61","about":"0","source":"Twitter","id":"22524","query":"obama"}]}

Comment: I tried putting your JSON into http://jsonlint.com/ and it worked. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Yes, it worked. Any idea of what could be wrong when I put dataType: "json" and nothing happens?

Comment: Can you see the actual output of the PHP script/AJAX call using Chrome's network window? https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network#network_panel_overview Make sure there are no MySQL errors and stuff. The reason you get no error when you don't put dataType: "json" is because the JSON parser is not attempting to read your malformed JSON. For some reason, your example JSON is good but whatever AJAX is receiving is not good.

Comment: This JSON that I posted here is exactly what is being sent to AJAX, after all the MySQL code is executed and in the end of the PHP file, so I have no idea of what is happening. I have tried using jQuery.parseJSON as well (instead of dataType) and I got an error.
I have checked the network window and it seems fine, although I don't have much experience using it.

Comment: What is the error from jQuery.parseJSON? That is the same parser enabled with dataType: "json"

Comment: That is the error: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-1.9.1.js:541
jQuery.extend.parseJSON jquery-1.9.1.js:541
$.ajax.success Analysis.php:425
fire jquery-1.9.1.js:1037
self.fireWith jquery-1.9.1.js:1148
done jquery-1.9.1.js:8074
callback

Comment: See that? `Unexpected token <`. That means your output has a < in it somewhere that is NOT compliant with JSON. From the network window, select your AJAX call and look at the response tab. This will show you the real output. Kinda frustrating

Comment: I pasted the output from the network window on jsonlint.com and it said it was valid. Don't know what else to do :(

Comment: I got it!!!!!!! What a stupid thing it was! I had the following code commented after my php code (including echo json_encode), and somehow it was getting in the end of what was being sent to AJAX. 

<!--  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cvi_busy_lib.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


// jQuery Document
$(document).ready(function(){
 var tval;
 
 $("#cancelrequest").click(function(){ 
  window.location = "index.php"
  return false;
 });
});

</script>

</div>
</HTML>-->

Comment: Thanks a lot for recommending the network window, that is what helped me!

Comment: You're welcome. I am going to post an answer. Please accept it as the right one :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you see the actual output of the PHP script/AJAX call using Chrome's network window?

Make sure there are no MySQL errors and stuff. The reason you get no error when you don't put `dataType: "json"` is because the JSON parser is not attempting to read your malformed JSON. For some reason, your example JSON is good but whatever AJAX is receiving is not good. From the network window, select your AJAX call and look at the response tab. This will show you the real output.